# GAE Sending emails with java stopped working suddenly with no changes to deployed app

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

I have a Google AppEngine java app (for this example: myapp) and have been sending e-mails from it for over a year.  I use sender e-mail address "DoNotReply@myapp.appspotmail.com" based on [GAE mail docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail) this should work.

The app was deployed on the 27th of September and the last e-mail that worked seems to have been sent on the 19th of October.

On Developer Console the "App Engine Release" is 1.9.28 and yet on the [Java Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/release-notes) the last documented version is 1.9.27.

How can something stop working if I didn't change the deployed application?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? Starting today I'm experiencing the same problem when the logged in user's email address is used as sender: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure  
(javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments  
(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unauthorized Sender: Unauthorized  
sender))

Comment: @Bytemaster, I did not find a solution.  We raised a ticket with GAE support and they looked into it.  It started working again for a while and now has stopped again.  In my case, I did not see any exceptions, so I think you have a different scenario